# RoboSpice-Retrofit POJO

Tags: android, json, robospice, retrofit

I have a JSON like this:

```
{"meta": {...}, "objects": [{...}, {...}]}
```

But the problem is how to construct the POJO class. From the samples there is only one example with simple JSON.

I tried with something like this:

```
class Test {
    public ArrayList<String> meta;

    public static class Object {
        public String testField;
    } 

    public static class Objects extends ArrayList<Object>{}
}
```

And in the RetrofitRequest class I use `Test.Objects.class`

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: can you post the whole json string?

Comment: It's something like this:
`{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1}, "objects": [{"description": "", "downloads": 0, "family_filter": 0, "id": 1, "image_url": "/static/img/wallpapers/1.jpg", "rating": 0.0, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/wallpapers/1/", "size": 895, "tags": "nature, leafs, autumn", "title": "Autumn Leafs ", "uploaded_date": "2013-11-06"}]}`

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it with creating classes for `meta` and `object` where objects are in `ArrayList<Object>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

***These are the POJO class to hold and parse the json***

**1)Meta.java**

```
public class Meta {
    private int limit;
    private String next;
    private int offset;
    private String previous;
    private int total_count;
    public int getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }
    public void setLimit(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    public String getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(String next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
    public int getOffset() {
        return offset;
    }
    public void setOffset(int offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
    }
    public String getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }
    public void setPrevious(String previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }
    public int getTotal_count() {
        return total_count;
    }
    public void setTotal_count(int total_count) {
        this.total_count = total_count;
    }

}
```

**2)Objects.java**

```
public class Objects {
    private String description;
    private int downloads;
    private int family_filter;
    private int id;
    private String image_url;
    private int rating;
    private String resource_uri;
    private int size;
    private String tags;
    private String title;
    private String uploaded_date;
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getDownloads() {
        return downloads;
    }
    public void setDownloads(int downloads) {
        this.downloads = downloads;
    }
    public int getFamily_filter() {
        return family_filter;
    }
    public void setFamily_filter(int family_filter) {
        this.family_filter = family_filter;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getImage_url() {
        return image_url;
    }
    public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
        this.image_url = image_url;
    }
    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public String getResource_uri() {
        return resource_uri;
    }
    public void setResource_uri(String resource_uri) {
        this.resource_uri = resource_uri;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
    public String getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
    public void setTags(String tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getUploaded_date() {
        return uploaded_date;
    }
    public void setUploaded_date(String uploaded_date) {
        this.uploaded_date = uploaded_date;
    }



}
```

**3) Finally your Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    private Meta meta;
    private List<Objects> objects;
    public Meta getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }
    public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }
    public List<Objects> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }
    public void setObjects(List<Objects> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }

}
```

Try like this.

This is complete POJO class which will hold the parsed json.

Comment: how you will acces received list elements?

`Test test = new Test();
test.getObjects();`

I tryed, and no result. I tryed also with iterator and no result too:
`while(test.getObjects().iterator().hasNext())
test.getObjects().iterator().next()`

Any advices?